# Input multiple values to multidimensional array C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an assignment where I have to make a program that takes in 3 sets of data of 5 values and adds them to a 3 * 5 array. I have already made a program where you type in each individual value, but I would rather want it to take in five values over 3 different inputs. 
The code is not finished. I also have to do some operations on the data but I got that covered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define THREE 3
#define FIVE 5

void totalArray(int, int, int set_numbers[][FIVE]);

void totalArray(int row, int column, int set_numbers[][FIVE]){
    int total, subtotal;
    printf("\tThe total of your 3-by-5 array is:\n");
  for(row = 0, total = 0; row < THREE; row++){
    // for each row, the numbers are summed
    for(column = 0, subtotal = 0; column < FIVE; column++){
      subtotal += set_numbers[row][column];
    printf("%d %d", row, subtotal);
    total += subtotal; // Total for entire array
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  // 2D array of 15 numbers declaration
  int set_numbers[THREE][FIVE] = {{}, {}, {}};
  //counter variables for the loop
  int i, j, column, row;
      printf("\tYou're given an array which is a 3 by 5 array.\n");
      printf("\tYou're going to put in each of the total 15 values.\n");
      printf("\t___________________________________________________\n");
      printf("\n\t\t\t--ATTENTION--\n");
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      printf("\n\t  ******************************************");
      printf("\n\t  **   Array values have to be integers   **");
      printf("\n\t  ******************************************");
      printf("\n\tWhich values do you want in set_numbers[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &set_numbers[i][j]);
    }
  }
      totalArray(row, column, set_numbers);

      printf("The average of your three sets of numbers are: \n\n");
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      printf("%d", set_numbers[i][j]);
      if(j == 4){
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I should specify, that what i want it to do, is take in sets of data. Something along the lines of 
    `int array[][] = {{}, {}, {}}`

Comment: I should specify, that what i want it to do, is take in sets of data int array[][] = {{}, {}, {}}

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add details. There's a link just under the tags.

Comment: Some nitpicking, you have the macros `THREE` and `FIVE` for the size of the arrays (not very good names IMO, as the don't describe what they're for), but everywhere else you don't use them and opt to use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) instead. Why? You could use the macros even when printing the values.

Comment: As for what I believe your problem is, you want something like `for (int i = 0; i < THREE; ++i) { scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &set_numbers[i][0], ... etc ...); }`, but programatically for the actual reading? If not then please elaborate on what you mean by "sets" and how you want to read the input. Perhaps show an example session with the program and show how you want the input?

Comment: Well, the only reason I use macros is to satisfy my teacher. Kind of a lousy reason, but he will mark you down if you COULD have used macros, but didn't. I would much rather have the person state the size of the array, but that is also out of the scope of the assignment, so that would be another markdown.

Comment: That's os exactly what it want! :D

Comment: No I mean why do you use `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` instead of `for (i = 0; i < THREE; i++)`? Also you could use e.g. `printf("\tYou're given an array which is a %d by %d array.\n", TRHEE, FIVE);` instead. Then you could easily change `THREE` to some other value and the program would still work and print the right values.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. But why would you want to? What's wrong with a loop where you read a single value each iteration? For the user it won't really matter, and if you don't print any output in the inner loop the user won't even know about it. And the user can still write all five numbers on a single line, the `scanf` function handles it even if you only read one value at a time in a loop.

Comment: Oh, just some minor prototyping mistakes. I hadn't made the macros when I wrote the for loop.

Comment: Again because i don't want to be marked down. We have to stick to the assignment exactly or we will be downgraded. It's terrible but necessary my teacher insists.

Comment: @AnonymousBruger Still, you should name the macros better. For instance `COLS` and `ROWS`.

Comment: There's no way to use `scanf` to read a variable number of values unless you do it in a loop. The only workaround is to read a full line, tokenize it (with e.g. `strtok`), and parse each sub-string (with e.g. `strtol` or `sscanf`). That is much more work, much more complicated, and as such more prone to errors. You also have to keep track of the number of value read for each line (the user might enter five values on five lines, for example). Perhaps you should talk to your teacher to clarify the he or she means about "reading sets"?

Comment: As already mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude, You should really only use the macros, instead of hardcoding the actual values in the program. Consider you need to change the values later, then you need to go through the whole program again and change the according parts (which is relatively easy in your case, but just shouldn´t be). Consider also, you need to change them thereafter back again. That is the reason also, what the macros are meant for.

Comment: I am not really sure what the question is, but if you want to input a fixed set of values at a time, read a string with `fgets` and apply `sscanf` to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rename the macros `THREE`to `COLUMNS` and `FIVE` to `ROWS`, because it doesn´t make much sense to name macros after values. Consider, that you might want to change the values later and the understanding of what these macros are meant for is unclear at first sight.

Furthermore i don´t see any reason for declare the separate variables `column` and `row` inside of `main()` if you already have such macros. Please adjust that (You also need to change the declaration of `totalArray()` respectively).
Than you can incorporate this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) 
{
   scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &set_numbers[i][0], &set_numbers[i][1], &set_numbers[i][2], &set_numbers[i][3], &set_numbers[i][4]);
}
```

And you should really only use the macros, instead of hardcoding the actual values in the program. Consider you need to change the values later, then you need to go through the whole program again and change the according parts (which is relatively easy in your case, but just shouldn´t be). Consider also, you need to change them thereafter back again. That is the reason also, what the macros are meant for.

Comment: You'll get a compiler warning that there are not enough arguments supplied.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, of course, because he is indicating them in `totalArray()`. Rather the macros `COLUMNS` and `ROWS`should be used inside this function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean about `totalArray()`. Here, there are 4 arguments missing: 5 destination variables are needed, not one. Did you mean `scanf("%d", &set_numbers[i][0]);`?

Comment: @WeatherVane You´re right i´ve forget that. I´ve edited the post accordingly. I thought you have mean the arguments of `totalArray()` instead of the ones for the `scanf()`-statement.